# Show as Unrecognized Typeclass

Tags: compiler-errors, functional-programming, typeclass, purescript

So I'm playing "Purescript by Example" again and with the ch7 applicative validation code in particular. Was going through updating the code in the supplied modules since the language has since evolved ( ++ operator deprecated, qualified imports are more concise..) but just when I thought the modules would be in ship shape, I got an error from the compiler stating that I have an unknown typeclass called "Show" in the code. I'm not sure how this arises since Show is supposed to be included in purescript-prelude package...

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly importing `Prelude` too? Unlike in Haskell, it is not implicitly imported in PureScript - it's just a module like any other.